# how to avoid pbix selecting "first" value?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I have a **Clients** table, with columns:

- Name
- Number
- Parent
- Parent Number
- Owner

Whenever a client has same Parent as itself,for example:

---

- Name: Client 1
- Number: 12345
- Parent: Client 1
- Parent Number: 12345
- Owner: xyz

---

It means that it has no parent.

My problem comes when using a Matrix in Power BI…

In Rows I have

- Parent
- Name

When I choose Owner… automatically, it creates this “First Owner” and picks a “wrong” value…
[image]

I understand that since its grouping by, it just picks the first value… but the row does have a value, how can I force to select the owner?

(I guess the model is not ideal, but I would like to fix it with a measure or a calculated column).

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace the implicit measure with the following explicit measure. Based on the data you provided I came up with this. if it does not suffice, please provide sample data with more layers and I will try again.

```
Measure = 
VAR _name = max(tbl[name])
VAR _parent = max(tbl[parent])
VAR _owner = max(tbl[owner])
RETURN if(_name=_parent,BLANK(),_owner)
```

Comment: Thanks, but  Owner column shall be returned.